# C Quicksort makes the program crash when ordering different kind of arrays

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, quicksort

**Overview:**
I'm implementing a program that uses the quick sort algorithm to order different arrays which have different sizes and are ordered in different ways. Then I print out how long it took for each array to be ordered and how many exchanges and comparisons have been made.
It's a homework and I need to know all of the different times, exchanges and comparisons.

**What I tried**
Reading articles online, I found out that it might be my compiler, it might use too few memory and it blocks the compiling process so I have to compile in release mode. The release mode gives me the same problems. I tried online compilers but none of em work.

**How my program works**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define CINQUECENTO 500
#define MILLE 1000
#define DUEMILA 2000
#define CINQUEMILA 5000
#define DIECIMILA 10000
#define VENTIMILA 20000
#define CINQUANTAMILA 50000

typedef enum {ORINATO, INVERS, PARZ_ORDINATO, RANDOM} Ordine;
typedef enum{FIVEH, ONET, TWOT, FIVET, TENT, TWENTYT, FIFTYT} Dimensione;
int qconfronti=0, qscambi=0;

int *generaArray(int dimensione, Ordine ordine);
int perno(int* array, int primo, int ultimo);
void quickSort(int* array, int u, int v);
void calculateQuicktime(int *array, int dim);
void automaticQS();

int main(){
    
    automaticQS();

    return 0;
}

int *generaArray(int dimensione, Ordine ordine) {
    int i, j, n;
    int *array = malloc(dimensione * sizeof(int));

    if (!array){
        return NULL;
    }

    switch (ordine){
        case ORINATO:
           
            for (i = 0; i < dimensione; i++){
                array[i] = i;
              
            }
            break;
        case INVERS:
            n =0;
            for ( i = dimensione-1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
                array[i] = n;
                n++;
            }break;
        case PARZ_ORDINATO:
            for (i = 0; i < dimensione/2 ; i++) {
                array[i] = i;
            }
            for (j = i+1; j <dimensione; j++){
                n = rand();
                array[j] = n;

            }
            printf("\n");break;
        case RANDOM:
            for ( i = 0; i <= dimensione ; i++) {
                array[i] = rand();

            }break;
        case ESCI:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return array;

}
int perno(int* array, int primo, int ultimo){
    int i=primo;
    int j=ultimo+1;
    int supp=0;
    int pivot=array[primo];

    while(i<j){
        do{
            i=i+1;
            qconfronti++;
        }while(array[i]<=pivot);

        do{
            j=j-1;
            qconfronti++;
        }while(array[j]>pivot);

        if(i<j){
            supp=array[i];
            array[i]=array[j];
            array[j]=supp;
            qscambi++;
        }
    }
    supp=array[primo];
    array[primo]=array[j];
    array[j]=supp;
    qscambi++;
    return j;
}

void quickSort(int* array, int u, int v){
    int q=0;
    if(u==v){
        return ;
    }
    q=perno(array, u, v);
    if(u<q){
        quickSort(array, u, q-1);
    }
    if(q<v){
        quickSort(array, q+1, v);
    }

}

void calculateQuicktime(int *array, int dim){
    clock_t start, end;
    double t;
    qconfronti = 0;
    qscambi = 0;
    start = clock();
    quickSort(array,0, dim);
    end = clock();
    t = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("\nConfronti: %d \t Scambi: %d", qconfronti, qscambi);
    printf("\nTempo impiegato per %d elementi : %lf secondi", dim, t);
}

void automaticQS() {
    printf("\nQuick Sort");

    printf("\n\nOrdinati:\n");
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(CINQUECENTO, ORINATO), CINQUECENTO);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(MILLE, ORINATO), MILLE);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(DUEMILA, ORINATO), DUEMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(CINQUEMILA, ORINATO), CINQUEMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(DIECIMILA, ORINATO), DIECIMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(VENTIMILA, ORINATO), VENTIMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(CINQUANTAMILA, ORINATO), CINQUANTAMILA);

    printf("\n\nParzialmente ordinati:\n");
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(CINQUECENTO, PARZ_ORDINATO), CINQUECENTO);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(MILLE, PARZ_ORDINATO), MILLE);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(DUEMILA, PARZ_ORDINATO), DUEMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(CINQUEMILA, PARZ_ORDINATO), CINQUEMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(DIECIMILA, PARZ_ORDINATO), DIECIMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(VENTIMILA, PARZ_ORDINATO), VENTIMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(CINQUANTAMILA, PARZ_ORDINATO), CINQUANTAMILA);

    printf("\n\nInversamente ordinati:\n");
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(CINQUECENTO, INVERS), CINQUECENTO);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(MILLE, INVERS), MILLE);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(DUEMILA, INVERS), DUEMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(CINQUEMILA, INVERS), CINQUEMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(DIECIMILA, INVERS), DIECIMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(VENTIMILA, INVERS), VENTIMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(CINQUANTAMILA, INVERS), CINQUANTAMILA);

    printf("\n\nCasuali:\n");
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(CINQUECENTO, RANDOM), CINQUECENTO);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(MILLE, RANDOM), MILLE);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(DUEMILA, RANDOM), DUEMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(CINQUEMILA, RANDOM), CINQUEMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(DIECIMILA, RANDOM), DIECIMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(VENTIMILA, RANDOM), VENTIMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(CINQUANTAMILA, RANDOM), CINQUANTAMILA);
}
```

1. It generates an array which can have ordered numbers (0,1, 2, 3,4, 5...), partially ordered numbers (0,1,2,3,6,64,44...), inverted numbers (...6,5,4,3,2,1,0) and random numbers (42,64,2,7,53,25,1...);
2. It quick sorts the various arrays;
3. It prints out the stuff we need.

**Question**
Why is it that my program only prints out the ordered numbers array and then crashes giving me exit code 11?

Ps. I use CLion

Comment: Have you run the program in the debugger to see where it crashes?

Comment: `case ESCI:` doesn't compile since it is undefined. Once I remove that case your program crashes for me with a stack overflow after `calculateQuicktime` calls `quickSort` recursively 3574 times starting from `calculateQuicktime(generaArray(VENTIMILA, ORINATO), VENTIMILA);`

Comment: It crashes from the third partially ordered array. I just noticed that the random one works as well...@RetiredNinja

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes, my bad that was just for the rest of my program, i just deleted it from the post, sorry...

Comment: Yes, it crashes exactly there for me too! So you suggest we have a stack overflow there? I was thinking of that but I wasn't too sure....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few bugs ...

---

The bug you're currently experiencing ...

In `perno`, although you have `while (i < j)`, this does *not* prevent the `do/while` loop for `i` from going beyond the end of the array.

The segfault occurs when `primo` is 500 and `ultimo` is 1000, but `i` will reach 333800.

I added a fix to the `i` and `j` loops to stop when going out of bounds. This may or may not be the correct fix.

---

After applying that fix and rerunning the program, you [seem to] recurse indefinitely. `quickSort` is called with `v` set to 1000, but `u` is recursively set to `u + 1` (perhaps the pivot value is not set well).

Eventually, you recurse *infinitely* with a `u` value of 0 and a `v` value of `1`

You return early from `quickSort` on `if (u == v)`. That [probably] isn't a good enough test.

I tried `if ((v - u) < 2)` instead.

Now it [eventually] recurses infinitely with `u==251` and `v==455`.

This indicates that the `if (u < q)` and/or `if (q < v)` tests in `quickSort` are [probably] *not* adequate to prevent the infinite recursion.

I added some `assert` calls there to [at least] abort early on the first such recursion.

---

When you allocate an array with a dimension (e.g. `500`), you allocate that many elements.

But, passing this value to `quickSort` is incorrect. That's because the third `quickSort` argument is the index of the *last* element and *not* the length.

So, in `calculateQuicktime`, you want:

```
quickSort(array,0,dim - 1);
```

*Side note:* `calculateQuicktime` does *not* call `free` on `array`, so you are leaking memory [I added a `free` call].

---

Anyway, here's my [somewhat] refactored version of your code. I added debug printing with a `dbgprt` macro.

But, I really found the above bugs mostly by running under `gdb`.

Although this code is *not* a complete fix, it should give you some ideas:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define CINQUECENTO 500
#define MILLE 1000
#define DUEMILA 2000
#define CINQUEMILA 5000
#define DIECIMILA 10000
#define VENTIMILA 20000
#define CINQUANTAMILA 50000

typedef enum { ORINATO, INVERS, PARZ_ORDINATO, RANDOM } Ordine;
typedef enum { FIVEH, ONET, TWOT, FIVET, TENT, TWENTYT, FIFTYT } Dimensione;
int qconfronti = 0,
    qscambi = 0;

int *generaArray(int dimensione, Ordine ordine);
int perno(int *array, int primo, int ultimo);
void quickSort(int *array, int u, int v);
void calculateQuicktime(int *array, int dim);
void automaticQS();

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_lvl,_fmt...) \
    do { \
        if (opt_d >= _lvl) \
            printf(_fmt); \
    } while (0)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { \
    } while (0)
#endif

int opt_d;
int svlvl;

void
dbgpush(int newlvl)
{

    svlvl = opt_d;
    if (opt_d)
        opt_d = newlvl;
}

void
dbgpop(void)
{

    opt_d = svlvl;
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        char *cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch (cp[-1]) {
        case 'd':
            opt_d = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    setlinebuf(stdout);
    automaticQS();

    return 0;
}

int *
generaArray(int dimensione, Ordine ordine)
{
    int i,
     j,
     n;
    int *array = malloc(dimensione * sizeof(int));

    if (!array) {
        return NULL;
    }

    printf("generaArray: %d\n",dimensione);

    switch (ordine) {
    case ORINATO:
        for (i = 0; i < dimensione; i++) {
            array[i] = i;
        }
        break;
    case INVERS:
        n = 0;
        for (i = dimensione - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            array[i] = n;
            n++;
        }
        break;
    case PARZ_ORDINATO:
        for (i = 0; i < dimensione / 2; i++) {
            array[i] = i;
        }
        for (j = i + 1; j < dimensione; j++) {
            n = rand();
            array[j] = n;

        }
        printf("\n");
        break;
    case RANDOM:
        for (i = 0; i <= dimensione; i++) {
            array[i] = rand();

        }
        break;
#if 0
    case ESCI:
        break;
#endif
    default:
        break;
    }

    return array;
}

int
perno(int *array, int primo, int ultimo)
{
    int i = primo;
    int j = ultimo + 1;
    int supp = 0;
    int pivot = array[primo];

    dbgprt(1,"perno: ENTER primo=%d ultimo=%d pivot=%d\n",primo,ultimo,pivot);

    while (i < j) {
        dbgprt(2,"perno: OUTLOOP i=%d j=%d\n",i,j);

        do {
            i = i + 1;
#if FIX1
            if (i >= j)
                break;
#endif
            dbgprt(3,"perno: ILOOP i=%d array=%d\n",i,array[i]);
            qconfronti++;
        } while (array[i] <= pivot);

        do {
#if FIX1
            if (i >= j)
                break;
#endif
            j = j - 1;
            dbgprt(3,"perno: JLOOP j=%d array=%d\n",j,array[j]);
            qconfronti++;
        } while (array[j] > pivot);

        if (i < j) {
            dbgprt(2,"perno: SWAP\n");
            supp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = supp;
            qscambi++;
        }
    }

    supp = array[primo];
    array[primo] = array[j];
    array[j] = supp;

    qscambi++;

    dbgprt(1,"perno: EXIT j=%d\n",j);

    return j;
}

void
quickSort(int *array, int u, int v)
{
    int q = 0;

    dbgprt(1,"quickSort: ENTER u=%d v=%d\n",u,v);

#if ! FIX2
    if (u == v) {
#else
    if ((v - u) < 2) {
#endif
        dbgprt(1,"quickSort: EXIT\n");
        return;
    }

    q = perno(array, u, v);

    if (u < q) {
        assert(! ((q - 1) == v));
        quickSort(array, u, q - 1);
    }
    if (q < v) {
        assert(! ((q + 1) == u));
        quickSort(array, q + 1, v);
    }

    dbgprt(1,"quickSort: EXIT\n");
}

void
calculateQuicktime(int *array, int dim)
{
    clock_t start,
     end;
    double t;

    qconfronti = 0;
    qscambi = 0;
    start = clock();
    quickSort(array, 0, dim - 1);
    end = clock();
    t = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("\nConfronti: %d \t Scambi: %d", qconfronti, qscambi);
    printf("\nTempo impiegato per %d elementi : %lf secondi", dim, t);

    // NOTE/BUG: array is never freed (i.e. a memory leak)
#if 1
    free(array);
#endif
}

void
automaticQS()
{
    printf("\nQuick Sort");

    printf("\n\nOrdinati:\n");
    dbgpush(2);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(CINQUECENTO, ORINATO), CINQUECENTO);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(MILLE, ORINATO), MILLE);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(DUEMILA, ORINATO), DUEMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(CINQUEMILA, ORINATO), CINQUEMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(DIECIMILA, ORINATO), DIECIMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(VENTIMILA, ORINATO), VENTIMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(CINQUANTAMILA, ORINATO), CINQUANTAMILA);
    dbgpop();

    dbgpush(3);
    printf("\n\nParzialmente ordinati:\n");
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(CINQUECENTO, PARZ_ORDINATO), CINQUECENTO);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(MILLE, PARZ_ORDINATO), MILLE);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(DUEMILA, PARZ_ORDINATO), DUEMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(CINQUEMILA, PARZ_ORDINATO), CINQUEMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(DIECIMILA, PARZ_ORDINATO), DIECIMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(VENTIMILA, PARZ_ORDINATO), VENTIMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(CINQUANTAMILA, PARZ_ORDINATO), CINQUANTAMILA);
    dbgpop();

    printf("\n\nInversamente ordinati:\n");
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(CINQUECENTO, INVERS), CINQUECENTO);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(MILLE, INVERS), MILLE);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(DUEMILA, INVERS), DUEMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(CINQUEMILA, INVERS), CINQUEMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(DIECIMILA, INVERS), DIECIMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(VENTIMILA, INVERS), VENTIMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(CINQUANTAMILA, INVERS), CINQUANTAMILA);

    printf("\n\nCasuali:\n");
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(CINQUECENTO, RANDOM), CINQUECENTO);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(MILLE, RANDOM), MILLE);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(DUEMILA, RANDOM), DUEMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(CINQUEMILA, RANDOM), CINQUEMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(DIECIMILA, RANDOM), DIECIMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(VENTIMILA, RANDOM), VENTIMILA);
    calculateQuicktime(generaArray(CINQUANTAMILA, RANDOM), CINQUANTAMILA);
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

The above was done just with `gdb` but *not* desk checking your code against a working [Hoare] algorithm.

So, using the wikipedia entry for quicksort: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort a few more bug fixes ...

In `perno`, the `i` loop was failing for *two* reasons:

1. The initialization of `i` was `int i = primo;` instead of `int i = primo - 1;` This caused the loop to skip over [ignore] `array[primo]` as a candidate. See: `ORIG3`
2. The `i` loop termination condition was `while (array[i] <= pivot)` instead of `while (array[i] < pivot)`. See: `ORIG5` Note that your `j` loop did *not* have this issue.

With these fixes, the extra bounds checks I added in the `i` and `j` loops are no longer necessary (See: `ORIG1`).

The reason that `quickSort` would recurse infinitely was the fact that the recursive call inside it was: `quickSort(array,u,q-1);` instead of `quickSort(array,u,q);` See: `ORIG4`

I added a check in `calculateQuicktime` to check for the final array actually being sorted.

With this check, some tests wouldn't crash [or recurse infinitely], but the final array would *not* be in sort.

This was because my [attempted] fix of changing `if (u == v)` into `if ((v - u) < 2` was *incorrect*. Your original code was correct. See: `ORIG2`

Some additional stylistic suggestions:

While using a `#define` for certain constants is a *good* idea (e.g. `#define PI 3.14159`), it's less readable for simple numbers (e.g. `#define ONE 1` and `#define TWO 2`). So, I'd eliminate `CINQUECENTO`, etc.

I'd replace this with a static/global array for the test lengths (e.g. `testlen`).

And, even though they weren't used, the same goes for `FIVEH`, etc.

And, the test code in `automaticQS` is cumbersome. Each section is replicating a fair amount of the code. By creating a helper function (e.g. `testall`), the test code can be greatly simplified.

Anyway, here's the fully working code with all the additional changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>

#ifndef ORIG1
#define ORIG1   1
#endif

#ifndef ORIG2
#define ORIG2   1
#endif

#ifndef ORIG3
#define ORIG3   0
#endif

#ifndef ORIG4
#define ORIG4   0
#endif

#ifndef ORIG5
#define ORIG5   0
#endif

#if 0
#define CINQUECENTO 500
#define MILLE 1000
#define DUEMILA 2000
#define CINQUEMILA 5000
#define DIECIMILA 10000
#define VENTIMILA 20000
#define CINQUANTAMILA 50000
#else
int testlen[] = {
    500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 20000, 50000, -1
};
#endif

typedef enum { ORINATO, INVERS, PARZ_ORDINATO, RANDOM } Ordine;
#if 0
typedef enum { FIVEH, ONET, TWOT, FIVET, TENT, TWENTYT, FIFTYT } Dimensione;
#endif
int qconfronti = 0, qscambi = 0;

int *generaArray(int dimensione, Ordine ordine);
int perno(int *array, int primo, int ultimo);
void quickSort(int *array, int u, int v);
void calculateQuicktime(int *array, int dim);
void automaticQS();

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_lvl,_fmt...) \
    do { \
        if (opt_d >= _lvl) \
            printf(_fmt); \
    } while (0)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { \
    } while (0)
#endif

int opt_d;
int svlvl;

void
dbgpush(int newlvl)
{

    svlvl = opt_d;
    if (opt_d)
        opt_d = newlvl;
}

void
dbgpop(void)
{

    opt_d = svlvl;
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        char *cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch (cp[-1]) {
        case 'd':
            opt_d = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    setlinebuf(stdout);
    automaticQS();

    return 0;
}

int *
generaArray(int dimensione, Ordine ordine)
{
    int i, j, n;
    int *array = malloc(dimensione * sizeof(int));

    if (array == NULL)
        return NULL;

    dbgprt(1,"generaArray: %d\n",dimensione);

    switch (ordine) {
    case ORINATO:
        for (i = 0; i < dimensione; i++) {
            array[i] = i;
        }
        break;

    case INVERS:
        n = 0;
        for (i = dimensione - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            array[i] = n;
            n++;
        }
        break;

    case PARZ_ORDINATO:
        for (i = 0; i < dimensione / 2; i++) {
            array[i] = i;
        }
        for (j = i + 1; j < dimensione; j++) {
            n = rand();
            array[j] = n;

        }
        printf("\n");
        break;

    case RANDOM:
        for (i = 0; i <= dimensione; i++)
            array[i] = rand();
        break;

#if 0
    case ESCI:
        break;
#endif

    default:
        break;
    }

    return array;
}

int
perno(int *array, int primo, int ultimo)
{
#if ORIG3
    int i = primo;
#else
    int i = primo - 1;
#endif
    int j = ultimo + 1;
    int supp = 0;
    int pivot = array[primo];

    dbgprt(1,"perno: ENTER primo=%d ultimo=%d pivot=%d\n",primo,ultimo,pivot);

    while (i < j) {
        dbgprt(2,"perno: OUTLOOP i=%d j=%d\n",i,j);

        do {
            i = i + 1;
#if (! ORIG1)
            if (i >= j)
                break;
#endif
            dbgprt(3,"perno: ILOOP i=%d array=%d\n",i,array[i]);
            qconfronti++;
#if ORIG5
        } while (array[i] <= pivot);
#else
        } while (array[i] < pivot);
#endif

        do {
#if (! ORIG1)
            if (i >= j)
                break;
#endif
            j = j - 1;
            dbgprt(3,"perno: JLOOP j=%d array=%d\n",j,array[j]);
            qconfronti++;
        } while (array[j] > pivot);

        if (i < j) {
            dbgprt(2,"perno: SWAP\n");
            supp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = supp;
            qscambi++;
        }
    }

    supp = array[primo];
    array[primo] = array[j];
    array[j] = supp;

    qscambi++;

    dbgprt(1,"perno: EXIT j=%d\n",j);

    return j;
}

void
quickSort(int *array, int u, int v)
{
    int q = 0;

    dbgprt(1,"quickSort: ENTER u=%d v=%d\n",u,v);

#if ORIG2
    if (u == v) {
#else
    if ((v - u) < 2) {
#endif
        dbgprt(1,"quickSort: EXIT\n");
        return;
    }

    q = perno(array, u, v);

    if (u < q) {
        assert((q - 1) != v);
#if ORIG4
        quickSort(array, u, q - 1);
#else
        quickSort(array, u, q);
#endif
    }
    if (q < v) {
        assert((q + 1) != u);
        quickSort(array, q + 1, v);
    }

    dbgprt(1,"quickSort: EXIT\n");
}

void
calculateQuicktime(int *array, int dim)
{
    clock_t start, end;
    double t;

    qconfronti = 0;
    qscambi = 0;
    start = clock();
    quickSort(array, 0, dim - 1);
    end = clock();
    t = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("Confronti: %d \t Scambi: %d\n", qconfronti, qscambi);
    printf("Tempo impiegato per %d elementi : %lf secondi\n", dim, t);

    // check array to ensure it's sorted
    int err = 0;
    int old = array[0];
    for (int idx = 1;  idx < dim;  ++idx) {
        int cur = array[idx];
        if (cur < old) {
            printf("calculateQuicktime: BADSORT idx=%d old=%d cur=%d\n",
                idx,old,cur);
            err = 1;
        }
        old = cur;
    }
    if (err)
        exit(1);

    // NOTE/BUG: array is never freed (i.e. a memory leak)
#if 1
    free(array);
#endif
}

void
testall(Ordine order,const char *reason)
{

    printf("\n\n%s:\n",reason);

    for (int *len = testlen;  *len >= 0;  ++len) {
        printf("\n");
        int *arr = generaArray(*len,order);
        calculateQuicktime(arr,*len);
    }
}

void
automaticQS()
{
    printf("\nQuick Sort");

    testall(ORINATO,"Ordinati");
    testall(PARZ_ORDINATO,"Parzialmente ordinati");
    testall(INVERS,"Inversamente ordinati");
    testall(RANDOM,"Casuali");
}
```